# list of pointers operator= c++ infinite loop

Tags: c++, list, pointers, reference, operators

I have a project of movies and workers.
on my main class, I have a list of both:

```
class MovieIndustry {

list<Movie> movies;   //list of all movies
list<Worker*> workers; //list of pointers to relevant type of Workers
```

I have a problem with operator= in Movie Class, everytime a movie has a worker it cant be overloaded..

```
 int main(){
            Movie g,s;
            Worker* w= new Director();
            g.addWorker(w);
            s=g;  //infinite loop
            s.printWorkersInMovie();
        }

class Movie{
std::list<Worker*> workersInMovie;

Movie& Movie:: operator= (const Movie& other) {
Worker* toAdd = NULL;
Genre* addGenre;

if (other.getNumOfWorkers () > 0  )
{       
for (workit=other.getWorkersInMovie().begin(); workit != 
other.getWorkersInMovie().end(); ++workit)
            {
                toAdd= (*workit);
                this->addWorker(toAdd);

 //HERE IT GETS INIFINITE LOOP WHEN I DO MOVIE3 =MOVIE1+MOVIE2
            }
  }
return *this;
}
```

addWorker code (workers inMovie is list::)

```
void Movie::addWorker(Worker* toAdd) {

workersInMovie.push_back(toAdd);
numOfWorkers++;
}
```

default constrctor:

```
Movie::Movie() {
m_classifier = NULL;
workersInMovie.empty();
genresOfMovie.empty();
length =0;
numOfWorkers=0;
numOfGenres=0;
}
```

copy constructor:

```
Movie::Movie(const Movie& toCopy) {

  cout << "inside copy" << endl;
 *this=toCopy;
}
```

I guess i need to delete the pointer toAdd inn the operator= but i dont know how to do that without getting to infinite loop..
HELP...?

Comment: Please simplify this code into a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There's plenty you can do to cut this down and you may discover the problem yourself while doing so.

Comment: ok i cut it a little bit.. this is minimal

Comment: Okay.  Where's the `operator+` definition for `Movie`?  Seems you're using it here: `final = final + (*it2);`  Also, I **strongly** suggest you avoid using operators for anything other than their mathematical definition.  It seems that's what led you to this error in the first place.  Just name them something intuitive, like `takeFrom` or `combineWith`.  There's no way an onlooker (like us) can know what `Movie + Movie` means.

Comment: added operator+, forgot that one..

Comment: Where do these `Worker*` come from?  Who allocates?  Who frees?

Comment: ok, in main class (MovieIndustry) i have a list of them as u can see. and i want each movie to be able to add a pointers to "workers" list in the main class. this is the problem, i can perform operator + when the 2 movies don't have workers in it, but if one of them has the program gets stuck in the loop of the adding.. probably deletes the pointers from the main class.. quite sure the problem is in the loop of operator = or operator+, but cant understand how to reference to those pointers without anything gets deleted..

Comment: Okay, in your `workit` for loop, you leave out the increment statement.  Inside the loop, you use `continue`, but `continue` calls the increment statement which you've left out.  See where I'm getting at?

Comment: I showed you where i get to inifnite loop

Comment: Does `addWorker` call `operator+`?  Once `if( (*workit)-> getId() == (*checkSecond) ->getId())` evaluates to true, it will never leave that loop.  (Also, this is why you need to make an mvce.  Build it from scratch if you have to... otherwise I'm going to need your whole source code which I _really_ don't feel like looking through)

Comment: no other mentioning operator+ in the code

Comment: `//HERE IT GETS INIFINITE LOOP WHEN I DO MOVIE3 =MOVIE1+MOVIE2`

Comment: uhh ok from my main class, using Movie final as u mentioned..

Comment: Ok then, do me a favor, and rename `operator+` and `operator=` to what they're actually trying to do.  `operator=` means "to make an exact copy of", but it looks like you're _extending_ instead?  I'm not even sure what your `operator+` is trying to do.  This will be a lot easier to figure out if I know what your functions want to do.

Comment: forget about the operator+, i figured problem is only with operator=.. I editted the post.
no idea how to solve this one

Comment: What does `addWorker` do?

Comment: i added it to the post.. gets a pointer, push_back into a list

Comment: Where is `workit` declared?  You just assign to it from out of nowhere.  There should be a declaration with a type somewhere if this code is compiling.

Comment: its in that class.. i dont think those are the problem snce everything else works.. i just cant copy the two lists of pointers, so if you can just take a look into that loop

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at the loop.  There isn't enough information to figure it out.  The only thing I can think of from what you have here, is that `workit` is the wrong type and not incrementing correctly, so it never actually "equals" the end.  Are you sure it's of the type `std::list<Worker*>::iterator`?

Comment: Also, you may just be better off using the STL.  You're using `std::list` already...  Why not just use `workersInMovie.insert(workersInMovie.end(), other.workersInMovie.begin(), other.workersInMovie.end());`?